# Cloud Functions Puppeteer TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to do some webscraping and am putting them on a scheduled pubsub using Firebase Cloud Functions. I am getting the above error message and have not been able to solve it. I have reviewed this [post](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4796), and understands that I need to wait till puppeteer is done.

When the pubsub function executes, the code needs to go to a few pages of a website to extract selected items. After extracting the items, I will then perform other tasks on them, ie compare and save to firestore.

My current implementation appears to have done that, so I have no idea how else should I amend my code. Here's my implementation:

```
//Entry function in functions/index.js
exports.scrapeWeb = functions.pubsub
.onRun((context) => {
    var scraper = new Scraper();
    return scraper.start();
})

//Scraper's start() function
Scraper.prototype.scrape = async function() {
    var scraped_items = []
    var promises = []

    //Loop over agencies
    for (const agency of agencies) {

        //Loop over required number of pages
        for (page_num = 0; page_num < num_of_pages; page_num++) {
            var promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                const url = setupUrl(agency, page_num);
                var data = {
                    ...
                }
                try {
                    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(constants.puppeteerOptions);
                    const page = await browser.newPage();
                    await page.setUserAgent(constants.userAgent);
                    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 0});            
                    await page.waitForSelector('div.container', {timeout: 0});
                    const body = await page.$eval('body', el => el.innerHTML);
                    data['html'] = body;
                    resolve(data);
                    await browser.close();                    
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log("Puppeteer error", err);
                }
            });

            promises.push(promise)
        }
    }

    const results = await Promise.all(promises)
    for (const result of results) {
        const scraped = scrapeHtml(result);
        console.log(`Scrapped ${scraped.length}`)
        scraped_items.push.apply(scraped_circulars, scraped);
    }

    //Do other stuffs with scraped_items
    return;
}

//Puppeteer options
puppeteerOptions: {
        headerless: true,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
        ]
    }
```

Would anyone be able to advice?

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to return a promise that resolves when all the work is complete.  Right now, it always returns nothing:

```
return scraper.start();
```

The last line of `start()`:

```
//Do other stuffs with scraped_items
return;
```

`start()` should return the stated promise.

The async/await code you're using isn't actually blocking the execution of start().  In a very general sense, you're not dealing with async/await and promises correctly, and it's not a good idea to mix up async/await syntax along with `new Promise`.

General advice - if you want to use async/await anywhere in your function, you should use it everywhere.  Make the top-level funciton callback async, and all of the other method async, and it will be easier to reason about what you code is doing.